# RUBY | Find a way to find an exception on the same word to capitalize

Tags: ruby

```
def titleize(string)

nocaps = ["the","and"]
puts string.split(" ").map { |word| nocaps.include?(word) ? word : word.capitalize }.join(" ")

end

titleize("the bridge over the river kwai")
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
######Render => "the Bridge Over the River Kwai"

######Expected rendering => "The Bridge Over the River Kwai"
```

Hello i present you my piece of code, the rendering gives
"the Bridge Over the River Kwai"
While I would like
"The Bridge Over the River Kwai"
So I would like to find a way to find an exception on the same word.

Comment: @jad examples : " and and " => " And and " or  "winter is coming in winter" =>"Winter Is Coming In winter"

Comment: I don't think the Rails tag is appropriate as this is  a pure-Ruby question.

Comment: @pharaoh2000 : Wouldn't `titleize(s).capitalize` to do what you want? If not, I fear that your question is not really clear.

Comment: @user1934428 not exactly. `capitalize`: *"Returns a copy of str with the first character converted to uppercase and the remainder to lowercase."*

Comment: @engineersmnky : Thanks a lot! Was not aware of this.

Answer (score 2):

your code, but always capitalise the first letter, using `each_with_index` to get the position in the array:

```
def titleize(string)
  nocaps = ["the","and"]
  string.split(" ").each_with_index.map { |word, i| i.positive? && nocaps.include?(word) ? word : word.capitalize }.join(" ")
end

titleize("the bridge over the river kwai")
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is as follows.

```
def titleize(str, little_words)
  str.downcase.split.map.with_index do |word,i|
    little_words.include?(word) && i > 0 ? word : word.capitalize
  end.join(" ")
end
```

```
str = "the briDge over   The river kwai"
```

```
titleize(str, ["the", "and"])
  #=> "The Bridge Over the River Kwai"
```

Here's a second way that operates on the string directly (rather than converting it to an array or words, perform substitutions for those words and then joining the resulting array):

```
def titleize(str, little_words)
  str.downcase.gsub(/(?<= )\p{L}+/) do |s|
    little_words.include?(s) ? s : s.capitalize
  end
end
```

```
titleize(str, ["the", "and"])
  #=> "The Bridge Over   the River Kwai"
```

Notice that this method preserves extra spaces between words in `str`.

The regular expression reads, "match one or more Unicode letters (`\p{L}+`) (greedily) preceded by a space".

A variant of this is to capitalize all words not in `little_words` and then capitalize the first character of the resulting string:

```
def titleize(str, little_words)
  str.downcase.gsub(/\p{L}+/) do |s|
    little_words.include?(s) ? s : s.capitalize
  end.tap { |s| s[0] = s[0].upcase }
end
```

See [Object#tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-tap).

If `little_words` contains many words the methods could be sped up by first converting that array to a set `little_words_set` (`require 'set'; little_words_set = little_words.to_set`) and then substituting `little_words_set` wherever `little_words` now appears.

This can be improved upon by taking a page from @Todd's answer: replace `downcase` with `capitalize`, obviating the need for the `tap` clause.

Note that [little words](https://www.onestopenglish.com/ask-the-experts/grammar-teaching-little-words-big-grammar/144972.article) is a term used in the publishing industry.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

## Capitalize String Before Per-Word Capitalization

There are a lot of ways to do this, but one way is to capitalize the whole String object before deciding whether or not to capitalize individual words. For example:

```
def titleize str 
  stopwords   = %w[the and]
  title_words = str.capitalize.split.map! do |word| 
    stopwords.include?(word) ? word : word.capitalize
  end.join ?\s
end

p titleize("the bridge over the river kwai")
#=> "The Bridge Over the River Kwai"

p titleize("the bridge over the river kwai and the amazon")
#=> "The Bridge Over the River Kwai and the Amazon"
```

Under the hood this will actually downcase everything but the first letter, and then programmatically capitalize each word that isn't in *stopwords*. So, it relies on some implicit behavior, but works well for the examples posted.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers are to the point of your original post I thought I would offer another alternative using a regular expression.

```
def titleize(str) 
  nocaps = ["the","and"]
  str.gsub(/\A.|\b(!?#{Regexp.union(nocaps)})\b\w+/,&:capitalize) 
end 
titleize("the bridge over the river and through the woods kwai")
#=> "The Bridge Over the River and Through the Woods Kwai"
```

This regex will select the first letter `\A.` and any other words that are not contained in the `nocaps` `Array` then it will substitute each selected word with capitalized version.

The resulting regex in this case is `/\A.|\b(?!(?-mix:the|and))\b\w+/` [Example](https://rubular.com/r/xNuWsJA7fcVgk8)